# CSS: Keep HTML tags and hide only text content inside an <a> tag

Tags: html, css

There's an "a" with an "img" in it followed by the link's text. I need to hide these link text without hiding the "img" tag.

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/page">
    <img src="images/example.jpg" width="50" />
    This is a link
</a>
```

In this "a" tag I need to hide the "This is a link" part only leaving just the "img" tag to display. There's no way to change the HTML content (add or remove new HTML tags). How can I do this?

Comment: You can use the `visibility` property in css, but that only hides it and it still takes space. Or to hide it completely use `display: none`.

Comment: you take the content of a (innerHTML), you split after the > of img, and put back only the first part

Comment: So there's no CSS way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the rest of the `html`or the use case maybe you could get away with just setting the size of the `a` tag and `font-size` property to zero.

```css
a {
  font-size: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com/page">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" width="50" />
    This is a link
</a>
```